# How to auto-complete a form field with a city and state?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a free form textfield that allows a user to type in a city and state, e.g. "Chicago, IL".

What I would like to do is when the user starts typing, to begin displaying suggestions of completed city+state combinmations (much like how Stackoverflow auto-suggestions the "tags" field below when you create a question).

**Question**: Does an API exist that returns every U.S.A city + state combination? Or can I download every city+state that exists in the USA from somewhere?

Comment: Just a suggestion -- how about prompting for ZIP code first, then fill in the City and State from a lookup? For ZIP codes that span more than one city, a radio-button list of the choices would work.

Comment: Is this really worth the effort?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a number of solutions available for the same task, you can **[try out this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3752.html)**. Also you will have to **[download USA states mysql database](http://www.colorplexstudios.com/articles/us_states_mysql_table/)** and then modify the table names or the script for the autocomplete class to work successfully.

Here is another good-looking option available.

http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of any existing APIs to do this exact thing for you, but here's some tools to get you started:

- (Data to use for auto-completion) http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt

Then you could just return the top 5 cities/state combos that match whatever first input the user has entered after each keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

http://geonames.org has an API to search for every city, landmark, mountain, etc. I use it myself. As for auto complete, the other answers are good resources.